# Chosing Data from MySql Tabl by selecting item in ComboBox

Tags: java, mysql, combobox

I have a JCombobox which is getting the data from a column of a MySql Table.

```
  public void FillCombo1(){
  try {
    String sql = "SELECT `Expense Code` FROM `database`.`expense_code_master`";

    PreparedStatement pst = (PreparedStatement)conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs = pst.executeQuery();

    while (rs.next()) {
        String name = rs.getString("Expense Code");
        comboBox.addItem(name);
    }
    }catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: "+ex);
  }
}
```

Now I want to get a value from same table which is related to the value which I have selected in the combobox. How can I do this?

```
Table schema:

Expense Code (primary key) | Account No (int)
E120                       | 12222
```

So I want to get the value (Account No) and put it with an ActionListener in an JLabel

Comment: You haven't asked a question, what part are you having trouble with?  Do you not know how to write the query, not know how to add a component to your GUI, etc.?  You need to provide more details, possibly show your code for your JComboBox and the MySQL table access, and ask a specific question on where you are stuck.

Comment: I don't know how to write the query.

Comment: How are the values related?  You need to provide the table layout (column names, types, etc.)

Comment: The Column "Expense Code" is the primary key and I want to get the value from the column "Account No". So when I select an Expense Code the Account No should appear.

Comment: You need to add the info to your question. What are the data types of the columns? Which column do you need to get data out of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize `ItemListener` to accomplish this.

```
JLabel myLabel = ... // Example JLabel from other part of program
...

class ItemChangeListener implements ItemListener{
    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event){ // Fired on selection
        if(event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED){ // Check for selection
            Object item = event.getItem(); // Here is selected item
            String expenseCode = item.toString(); // Get String

            String result = ...; // Use query here - 
                                 // same way as with your other query

            myLabel.setText(result); // Update JLabel with found String
        }
    }       
}
```

Make sure to add the `ItemChangeListener` to your `JComboBox`.

```
comboBox.addItemListener(new ItemChangeListener());
```

---

The `SQL` query would be something like this.

```
// expenseCode would be the String you got in the itemStateChanged method
String sql2 = "SELECT `Account No` FROM `database`.`expense_code_master` " + 
              "WHERE `Expense Code` == `" + expenseCode + "`";
```